# how to check whether a particular string is in a series of string stored in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

so actually i'm writing client/server programs using TCP/IP. In this case, client can upload file and choose whether the file is shared to public,group,or private. The problem is when the client choose to share the file to group(other clients/members). As a beginner, i have no idea to store a string array which is contains the name of the selected members into SQL database. So, i decided it to create a long string like the example below.

```
//assume this is the long string stored in column called "member"

 //this is row1// "Lexus,Mitsubishi,Bmw,Audi,Ford"

//this is row2// "12345678,456789,54321,87654321,Lexus"
```

then i want to check whether "Lexus" is in those strings above. If it exists, then i will show those two rows.

So the main point is, i really want to know how to write the SQL Query in this case, and perhaps you have the best way to solve this problem.

Thank you for helping me, currently it's working with 'LIKE' operator.

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE ROW1 LIKE '%LEXUS%'
```

but i think the problem is not solved yet even though it is working, because i'm still using a single long string. I agree with Tim's suggestion that i need to create another table, but i think i need more tutorials about connecting two tables using primary key and foreign key

Comment: Don't store strings in a column. You should use a table to store all your members(e.g. `Lexus` and `Mitsubishi`, ...). All members have a primary key(normally `int`). Then you should use this key as foreign-key in the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `LIKE` operator?

`SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE ROW1 LIKE '%LEXUS%'`

Comment: This will not allow any of the possible values to be embedded in any of the other possible values.  In the example, it doesn't allow a member name of "Lex" or "Lexus82".

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you made a mistake when you decided to store a single long string.  It is a violation of database normalization principles to store more than one datum in a single column.

The correct approach is that each separate value goes in its own row in a table created just to store these values.  Each row in that table has two values, a key value pointing back to the original table, and a the single text value you're storing.

The best solution is to refactor your database at the earliest possible moment to avoid investing more programming time in a design that will only cause you headaches down the road.

If that's not possible, we need to know more about which database product you're using.  Some of them have built in functions to handle this kind of query (for instance FIND_IN_SET in MySQL) but these work-arounds never have good performance and are non-standard from one product to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%Lexus%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Explore SQL **Full Text Search** and declare member column as full text column and then use WHERE CONTAIN predicate to find some string with in that full text column. Use link

```
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx
```